# How do numpy's in-place operations (e.g. `+=`) work?

Tags: python, numpy

The basic question is: What happens under the hood when doing: `a[i] += b`?

Given the following:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(4)
i = a > 0
i
= array([False,  True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
```

I understand that:

- `a[i] = x` is the same as `a.__setitem__(i, x)`, which assigns directly to the items indicated by `i`
- `a += x` is the same as `a.__iadd__(x)`, which does the addition in place

*But what happens when I do*:

```
a[i] += x
```

Specifically:

1. Is this the same as `a[i] = a[i] + x`?  (which is not an in-place operation)
2. Does it make a difference in this case if `i` is:

   - an `int` index, or
   - an `ndarray`, or
   - a `slice` object

---

*Background*

The reason I started delving into this is that I encountered a non-intuitive behavior when working with duplicate indices:

```
a = np.zeros(4)
x = np.arange(4)
indices = np.zeros(4,dtype=np.int)  # duplicate indices
a[indices] += x
a
= array([ 3.,  0.,  0.,  0.])
```

More interesting stuff about duplicate indices in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15973827/handling-of-duplicate-indices-in-numpy-assignments/16033516#16033516).

Comment: I don't see a problem with your background example. It clearly needs to iterate internally over all the values. If you assign values to an array as an in-place operation in which all the indices are the same, the last one is going to clobber the rest. This is clearly what happens (the last value of `x` clobbers all the rest).

Comment: Oh, I see the problem. If internally you're actually writing back to memory the result of the operation, you'd expect so see the sum of all the values in `x`. hmmm...

Comment: @HenryGomersall, exactly.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The first thing you need to realise is that `a += x` doesn't map exactly to `a.__iadd__(x)`, instead it maps to `a = a.__iadd__(x)`. Notice that the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iadd__) specifically says that in-place operators return their result, and this doesn't have to be `self` (although in practice, it usually is). This means `a[i] += x` trivially maps to:

```
a.__setitem__(i, a.__getitem__(i).__iadd__(x))
```

So, the addition *technically* happens in-place, but only on a temporary object. There is still potentially one less temporary object created than if it called `__add__`, though.

Comment: Nice, thanx for the tip! Is there any danger about running a.__iadd__(a) ?

Answer (score 7):

Actually that has nothing to do with numpy. There is no "set/getitem in-place" in python, these things are equivalent to `a[indices] = a[indices] + x`. Knowing that, it becomes pretty obvious what is going on. (EDIT: As lvc writes, actually the right hand side is in place, so that it is `a[indices] = (a[indices] += x)` if that was legal syntax, that has largly the same effect though)

Of course `a += x` actually is in-place, by mapping a to the `np.add` `out` argument.

It has been discussed before and numpy cannot do anything about it as such. Though there is an idea to have a `np.add.at(array, index_expression, x)` to at least allow such operations.

Comment: the at reduction of ufuncs has been added to numpy 1.8.0

Comment: @seberg: Are you sure about a[:] = a[:]+x is the same as a+=x ? They sure yield the same results, but unless I made an error, the latter version is significantly faster for large arrays.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know what's going on under the hood, but in-place operations on items in NumPy arrays and in Python lists will return the same reference, which IMO can lead to confusing results when passed into a function.

## Start with Python

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = a
>>> a is b
True
>>> id(a[2])
12345
>>> id(b[2])
12345
```

*... where `12345` is a unique `id` for the location of the value at `a[2]` in memory, which is the same as `b[2]`.*

So `a` and `b` refer to the same list in memory. Now try in-place addition on an item in the list.

```
>>> a[2] += 4
>>> a
[1, 2, 7]
>>> b
[1, 2, 7]
>>> a is b
True
>>> id(a[2])
67890
>>> id(b[2])
67890
```

So in-place addition of the item in the list only changed the value of the item at index `2`, but `a` and `b` still reference the same list, although the 3rd item in the list was reassigned to a new value, `7`. The reassignment explains why if `a = 4` and `b = a` were integers (or floats) instead of lists, then `a += 1` would cause `a` to be reassigned, and then `b` and `a` would be different references. However, if list addition is called, *eg*: `a += [5]` for `a` and `b` referencing the same list, it does **not** reassign `a`; they will both be appended.

## Now for NumPy

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([1, 2, 3], float)
>>> b = a
>>> a is b
True
```

Again these are the same reference, and in-place operators seem have the same effect as for list in Python:

```
>>> a += 4
>>> a
array([ 5.,  6.,  7.])
>>> b
array([ 5.,  6.,  7.])
```

In place addition of an `ndarray` updates the reference. This is not the same as calling `numpy.add` which creates a copy in a new reference.

```
>>> a = a + 4
>>> a
array([  9.,  10.,  11.])
>>> b
array([ 5.,  6.,  7.])
```

## In-place operations on borrowed references

I think the danger here is if the reference is passed to a different scope.

```
>>> def f(x):
...     x += 4
...     return x
```

The argument reference to `x` is passed into the scope of `f` which does not make a copy and in fact changes the value at that reference and passes it back.

```
>>> f(a)
array([ 13.,  14.,  15.])
>>> f(a)
array([ 17.,  18.,  19.])
>>> f(a)
array([ 21.,  22.,  23.])
>>> f(a)
array([ 25.,  26.,  27.])
```

The same would be true for a Python list as well:

```py
>>> def f(x, y):
...     x += [y]

>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = a
>>> f(a, 5)
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 5]
>>> b
[1, 2, 3, 5]
```

IMO this can be confusing and sometimes difficult to debug, so I try to only use in-place operators on references that belong to the current scope, and I try be careful of borrowed references.

Answer (score 3):

As Ivc explains, there is no in-place item add method, so under the hood it uses `__getitem__`, then `__iadd__`, then `__setitem__`.  Here's a way to empirically observe that behavior:

```
import numpy

class A(numpy.ndarray):
    def __getitem__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("getitem")
        return numpy.ndarray.__getitem__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    def __setitem__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("setitem")
        return numpy.ndarray.__setitem__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    def __iadd__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("iadd")
        return numpy.ndarray.__iadd__(self, *args, **kwargs)

a = A([1,2,3])
print("about to increment a[0]")
a[0] += 1
```

It prints

```
about to increment a[0]
getitem
iadd
setitem
```