# numpy.array.__iadd__ and repeated indices

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array:

```
A = np.array([0, 0, 0])
```

and list of indices with repetitions:

```
idx = [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2]
```

and another array i would like to add to A using indices above:

```
B = np.array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
```

The operation:

```
A[idx] += B
```

Gives the result: `array([1, 1, 1])`, so obviously values from `B` were not summed up. What is the best way to get as a result `array([2, 2, 2])`? Do I have to iterate over indices?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15973827/2096752 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/16034672/2096752

Comment: The first duplicate is not actually a duplicate, it talks about assignment which is completely different from addition.

Comment: I feel also the second duplicate is not an exact duplicate. Please remove this duplication info.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

for this numpy 1.8 added the `at` reduction:

> at(a, indices, b=None)
>
> Performs unbuffered in place operation on operand 'a' for elements
>   specified by 'indices'. For addition ufunc, this method is equivalent
>   to `a[indices] += b`, except that results are accumulated for elements
>   that are indexed more than once. For example, `a[[0,0]] += 1` will
>   only increment the first element once because of buffering, whereas
>   `add.at(a, [0,0], 1)` will increment the first element twice.
>
> .. versionadded:: 1.8.0

```
In [1]: A = np.array([0, 0, 0])
In [2]: B = np.array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
In [3]: idx = [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2]
In [4]: np.add.at(A, idx, B)
In [5]: A
Out[5]: array([2, 2, 2])
```

Comment: That's it! It seems to be couple of times faster than iterating and works also on multidimensional arrays. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
A = np.array([1, 2, 3])
idx = [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2]
A += np.bincount(idx, minlength=len(A))
```

Obviously it's even more simple if A starts off as zeros:

```
A = np.bincount(idx)
```