# Vectorize addition into array indexed by another array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization

I am trying to get a fast vectorized version of the following loop:

```
for i in xrange(N1):
   A[y[i]] -= B[i,:]
```

Here `A.shape = (N2,N3)`, `y.shape = (N1)` with `y` taking values in `[0,N2[`, `B.shape = (N1,N3)`. You can think of entries of `y` being indices into rows of `A`. Here `N1` is large, `N2` is pretty small and `N3` is smallish.

I thought simply doing

```
A[y] -= B
```

would work, but the issue is that there are repeated entries in `y` and this does not do the right thing (i.e., if `y=[1,1]` then `A[1]` is only added to once, not twice). Also this is does not seem to be any faster than the unvectorized for loop.

Is there a better way of doing this?

EDIT: YXD linked [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24099404/numpy-array-iadd-and-repeated-indices) to in comments which at first seems to fit the bill. It would seem you can do exactly what I want with

```
np.subtract.at(A, y, B)
```

and it does work, however when I try to run it it is *significantly slower* than the unvectorized version. So, the question remains: is there a more performant way of doing this?

EDIT2: An example, to make things concrete:

```
n1,n2,n3 = 10000, 10, 500
A = np.random.rand(n2,n3)
y = np.random.randint(n2, size=n1)
B = np.random.rand(n1,n3)
```

The for loop, when run using `%timeit` in ipython gives on my machine:

```
10 loops, best of 3: 19.4 ms per loop
```

The `subtract.at` version produces the same value for `A` in the end, but is much slower:

```
  1 loops, best of 3: 444 ms per loop
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [numpy.array.\_\_iadd\_\_ and repeated indices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24099404/numpy-array-iadd-and-repeated-indices) and http://stackoverflow.com/q/15973827/553404

Comment: @YXD, thanks for the suggestion, looked pretty good but it seems to make things slower in fact. I edited the question to address this.

Comment: Is `A` initialized to zeros, i.e. `A = np.zeros((N2,N3))` before going into the loop?

Comment: @Divakar, it is not. Will add a concrete example to question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code for the original for-loop based approach would look something like this -

```
def for_loop(A):
    N1 = B.shape[0]
    for i in xrange(N1):
       A[y[i]] -= B[i,:]
    return A
```

---

**Case #1**

If n2 >> n3, I would suggest this vectorized approach -

```
def bincount_vectorized(A):

    n3 = A.shape[1]
    nrows = y.max()+1
    id = y[:,None] + nrows*np.arange(n3)
    A[:nrows] -= np.bincount(id.ravel(),B.ravel()).reshape(n3,nrows).T
    return A
```

Runtime tests -

```
In [203]: n1,n2,n3 = 10000, 500, 10
     ...: A = np.random.rand(n2,n3)
     ...: y = np.random.randint(n2, size=n1)
     ...: B = np.random.rand(n1,n3)
     ...: 
     ...: # Make copies
     ...: Acopy1 = A.copy()
     ...: Acopy2 = A.copy()
     ...: 

In [204]: %timeit for_loop(Acopy1)
10 loops, best of 3: 19 ms per loop

In [205]: %timeit bincount_vectorized(Acopy2)
1000 loops, best of 3: 779 µs per loop
```

---

**Case #2**

If n2 << n3, a modified for-loop approach with lesser loop complexity could be suggested -

```
def for_loop_v2(A):
    n2 = A.shape[0]
    for i in range(n2):
        A[i] -= np.einsum('ij->j',B[y==i]) # OR (B[y==i]).sum(0)
    return A
```

Runtime tests -

```
In [206]: n1,n2,n3 = 10000, 10, 500
     ...: A = np.random.rand(n2,n3)
     ...: y = np.random.randint(n2, size=n1)
     ...: B = np.random.rand(n1,n3)
     ...: 
     ...: # Make copies
     ...: Acopy1 = A.copy()
     ...: Acopy2 = A.copy()
     ...: 

In [207]: %timeit for_loop(Acopy1)
10 loops, best of 3: 24.2 ms per loop

In [208]: %timeit for_loop_v2(Acopy2)
10 loops, best of 3: 20.3 ms per loop
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and the detailed analysis. I am interested in case #2 for which your method is only marginally faster, so will hold off on accepting for now in case somebody has a better method.

Comment: @toth Sure, no problem!

Comment: @toth See if the approaches listed in [`this other answer`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32283789/3293881) to a very similar question helps?