# Python: loop optimization

Tags: python, loops

I am quite new to Python but I've started using it for some data analysis and now I love it. Before, I used C, which I find just terrible for file I/O.

I am working on a script which computes the [radial distribution function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radial_distribution_function) between a set of N=10000 (ten thousands) points in a 3D box with periodic boundary conditions (PBC). Basically, I have a file of 10000 lines made like this:

```
0.037827 0.127853 -0.481895
12.056849 -12.100216 1.607448
10.594823 1.937731 -9.527205
-5.333775 -2.345856 -9.217283
-5.772468 -10.625633 13.097802
-5.290887 12.135528 -0.143371
0.250986 7.155687 2.813220
```

which represents the coordinates of the N points. What I have to do is to compute the distance between every couple of points (I hence have to consider all the 49995000 combinations of 2 elements) and then do some operation on it.

Of course the most taxing part of the program is the loop over the 49995000 combinations.

My current function looks like this:

```
    g=[0 for i in range(Nbins)]

for i in range(Nparticles):
    for j in range(i+1,Nparticles):

        #compute distance and apply PBC
        dx=coors[i][0]-coors[j][0]
        if(dx>halfSide):
            dx-=boxSide
        elif(dx<-halfSide):
            dx+=boxSide

        dy=coors[i][1]-coors[j][1]
        if(dy>halfSide):
            dy-=boxSide
        elif(dy<-halfSide):
            dy+=boxSide

        dz=coors[i][2]-coors[j][2]
        if(dz>halfSide):
            dz-=boxSide
        elif(dz<-halfSide):
            dz+=boxSide

        d2=dx**2+dy**2+dz**2

        if(d2<(cutoff*boxSide)**2):
            g[int(sqrt(d2)/dr)]+=2
```

Notice: `coors` is a nested array, created using `loadtxt()` on the data file.

I basically recycled a function that I used in another program, written in C.

I am not using `itertool.combinations()` because I have noticed that the program runs slightly slower if I use it for some reason (one iteration is around 111 s while it runs in around 106 with this implementation).

This function takes around 106 s to run, which is terrible considering that I have to analyze some 500 configuration files.

Now, **my question is**: is there general a way to make this kind of loops run faster using Python? I guess that the corresponding C code would be faster, but I would like to stick to Python because it is so much easier to use.

I would like to stress that even though I'm certainly looking for a particular solution to my problem, I would like to know how to iterate more efficiently when using Python *in general*.

PS Please try to explain the code in your answers as much as possible (if you write any) because I'm a newbie in Python.

**Update**

First, I want to say that I know that, since there is a cutoff, I could write a more efficient algorithm if I divide the box in smaller boxes and only compute the distances in neighboring boxes, but for now I would only like to speed up this particular algorithm.

I also want to say that using Cython (I followed this [tutorial](http://docs.cython.org/src/quickstart/build.html#building-a-cython-module-using-distutils)) I managed to speed up everything a little bit, as expected (77 s, where before it took 106).

Comment: If you're using python2.x, you'll want to use `xrange` rather than `range`.  If that doesn't get it going fast enough, you'll probably need to start using something like `numpy` and figure out how you can do the operations using numpy's vectorized functions.

Comment: Do you absolutly have to use nested for loops? thats usually a code smell and should be avoided

Comment: If numpy or pandas doesn't speed things up enough, Python also allows you to execute C code--you might want to check into that as well.

Comment: I'd try some basic math to avoid extra conditionals. For example: `if(dx>halfSide):
            dx-=boxSide
        elif(dx<-halfSide):
            dx+=boxSide` looks *a lot* like it could be simplified with `if abs(dx) < halfSide`.

Comment: Try to avoid loops completely. `numpy` is very well suited for this sort of thing.

Comment: Once the for loops are optimized, if `cutoff` is large, it is likely that `if(d2<(cutoff*boxSide)**2):
            g[int(sqrt(d2)/dr)]+=2` spends a large part of time. Computing a square root and a division is time consumming. The division can be easily avoided. Is binning by radius absolutely required? Otherwise, try  `one_dx2=1./(dx*dx) ... for, for ... g[int(d2*one_dx2)]+=2` If `cutoff` is small, there are bounding-box based improvements within the grasp of your hand!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If memory is not an issue (and it probably isn't given that the actual amount of data won't be different from what you are doing now), you can use `numpy` to do the math for you and put everything into an `NxN` array (around 800MB at 8 bytes/`float`).

Given the operations your code is trying to do, I do not think you need *any* loops outside `numpy`:

```
g = numpy.zeros((Nbins,))
coors = numpy.array(coors)

#compute distance and apply PBC
dx = numpy.subtract.outer(coors[:, 0], coors[:, 0])
dx[dx < -halfSide] += boxSide
dx[dx > halfSide)] -= boxSide
dy = numpy.subtract.outer(coors[:, 1], coors[:, 1])
dy[dy < -halfSide] += boxSide
dy[dy > halfSide] -= boxSide
dz = numpy.subtract.outer(coors[:, 2], coors[:, 2])
dz[dz < -halfSide] += boxSide
dz[dz > halfSide] -= boxSide

d2=dx**2 + dy**2 + dz**2
# Avoid counting diagonal elements: inf would do as well as nan
numpy.fill_diagonal(d2, numpy.nan)

# This is the same length as the number of times the
# if-statement in the loops would have triggered
cond = numpy.sqrt(d2[d2 < (cutoff*boxSide)**2]) / dr
# See http://stackoverflow.com/a/24100418/2988730
np.add.at(g, cond.astype(numpy.int_), 2)
```

The point is to always stay away from looping in Python when dealing with large amounts of data. Python loops are inefficient. They perform lots of book-keeping operations that slow down the math code.

Libraries such as `numpy` and `dynd` provide operations that run the loops you want "under the hood", usually bypassing the bookkeeping with a C implementation. The advantage is that you can do the Python-level book-keeping once for each enormous array and then get on with processing the raw numbers instead of dealing with Python wrapper objects (numbers are full blown-objects in Python, there are no primitive types).

In this particular example, I have recast your code to use a sequence of array-level operations that do the same thing that your original code did. This requires restructuring how you think about the steps a little, but should save a lot on runtime.

Comment: Thank you, very clear answer. There is a problem, though: I tried to run your code and I got the following error: at `dx = numpy.subtract.outer(coors[:, 0], coors[:, 0])` I get `list indices must be integers, not tuple`

Comment: @valerio92. That is because I assumed that your `coors` array was an array rather than a nested Python list. There are a couple of things you can do. The easiest would probably be to convert `coors` to a `numpy` array: `coors = numpy.array(coors)`. You can also look into the `pandas` library. It will easily load your file since it is basically a CSV. Pandas provides an extension to `numpy` that makes certain aspects of data analysis much easier.

Comment: I used `loadtxt` to create it so it came like this (a nested array). I will try to make it an array so that I can try your implementation.

Comment: `numpy.array(coors)` should work fine. I've even updated the answer since you made it explicit in the question. A list would be OK, but unfortunately you have a list of lines instead of columns. Such is life.

Comment: Now, at `np.add.at(g, int(cond), 2)`, I get `only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars`. Unfortunately my understanding of your code is really poor, so it is difficult for me to deal with the errors...

Comment: That's fine. I would recommend reading the docs. I will try to reproduce the error.

Comment: My mistake. Updated. I forgot `cond` was an array, tried casting it to a single int instead of converting the type.

Comment: Awesome!! It took 10 seconds!! I wish I could understand your code better so I could learn how to do such things in the future...Is there any tutorial to learn how to program properly using numpy?

Comment: As a matter of fact, yes. I would read through the official docs starting here: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/user/quickstart.html. After that, browse through all of the links that seem relevant. After that, look up the functions that I used here (just Google "numpy <functionname>" and the man-page will come up). Once you have some of the background down, I would recommend SO and Google as your primary resources. Most of the basic "How do I ..." have been hashed out pretty well here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115220/discussion-between-valerio92-and-mad-physicist).

Answer (score 2):

You've got an interesting problem there. There are some common guidelines for high performance Python; these are for Python2 but should carry for the most part to Python3.

- Profile your code. Using %timeit and %%timeit on jupyter/ipython is quick and fast for interactive sessions, but cProfile and line_profiler are valuable for finding bottlenecks.
- This a link to a short essay that covers the basics from the Python documentation that I found helpful:  https://www.python.org/doc/essays/list2str
- Numpy is a great package for vectorized operations. Note that numpy vectors are generally slower to work with than small-medium size lists but the memory savings are huge. Speed gain is substantial over lists when doing multi-dimensional arrays. Also if you start observing cache misses and page-faults with pure Python, then the numpy benefit will be even greater.
- I have been using Cython recently with a fair amount of success, where numpy/scipy don't quite cut it with the builtin functions.
- Check out scipy which has a huge library of functions for scientific computing. There's a lot to explore; eg., the scipy.spatial.pdist function computes fast nC2 pairwise distances. In the testrun below, 10k items pairwise distances completed in 375ms. 100k items will probably break my machine though without refactoring.

  ```
  import numpy as np
  from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist
  xyz_list = np.random.rand(10000, 3)
  xyz_list
  Out[2]: 
  array([[ 0.95763306,  0.47458207,  0.24051024],
         [ 0.48429121,  0.12201472,  0.80701931],
         [ 0.26035835,  0.76394588,  0.7832222 ],
         ..., 
         [ 0.07835084,  0.8775841 ,  0.20906537],
         [ 0.73248369,  0.60908474,  0.57163023],
         [ 0.68945879,  0.19393467,  0.23771904]])
  In [10]: %timeit xyz_pairwise = pdist(xyz_list)
  1 loop, best of 3: 375 ms per loop

  In [12]: xyz_pairwise = pdist(xyz_list)
  In [13]: len(xyz_pairwise)
  Out[13]: 49995000
  ```

Happy exploring!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, you gave me much food for thought! This function pdist is really cool, but how can I implement periodic boundary condition in it?

Comment: Kudos for introducing OP to scipy