# Unclarity on variable cloning behavior

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, operators, in-place

Along with a book I was provided with a Python program, into which I am digging deep now.

The program uses a global data structure named `globdat`, in a specific routine a numpy array inside `globdat` is assigned to a local variable:

```
a = globdat.array
```

Then in a following while loop the variable `a` is updated every iteration according to:

```
a[:] += da[:]
```

The result of this operation is that `globdat.array` is updated, which is used in subsequent operations.

Is the usage of `[:]` required here, or is it merely used to indicate that it also clones into `globdat.array`? Can anyone clarify this coding style?

Comment: Is `globdat.array` a python list or a numpy array or something else? It matters.

Comment: @StefanPochmann `globdat.array` is a numpy array indeed. I'm sorry if this changes the relevance of provided answers.

Comment: They seem to still be correct about the main question, but I'm a numpy newbie and can't tell for sure. I'll ask the top answerer, as I'm interested as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second `[:]`, in the right-hand-side, is redundant. It just copies `da` before using it in the concatenation, which is pointless.

We're left with:

```
a[:] += da
```

---

First, let's understand what `a += da` does.  It maps to:

```
a = a.__iadd__(da)
```

The call to `__iadd__` extends the original list `a`, and returns `self`, i.e. a reference to the list. The assignment which happens after, then, has no effect in this case (same as `a=a`).

This achieves the original goal, i.e. to extend the global array.

---

Now, What does `a[:] += da` do?  It maps to:

```
a[:] = a[:].__iadd__(da)
```

Or more tediously to:

```
a.__setitem__(slice(None), a.__getitem__(slice(None)).__iadd__(da))
```

For readability, let's write it as (not a valid python syntax):

```
a.__setitem__(:, a.__getitem__(:).__iadd__(da))
```

So `a[:].__iadd__(da)`:

1. creates a copy of `a` (call is `a2`)
2. concatenate `da` to `a2` in place
3. return `a2`

Then the assignment `a[:] = ...`:

4. replaces all values in `a` with all values in `a2` in place.

So that too, achieves the original goal, but is wayyyyyy less efficient.

---

There are some interesting details about this stuff in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16034672/2096752).

Comment: Can you tell whether the slicings make any sense for numpy arrays (or mix of array and list)? The OP confirmed my suspicion and updated the question, and I'm curious about it as well.

Answer (score 4):

This statement is rather nasty:

```
a[:] += da[:]
```

It translates into this:

```
a.__setitem__(slice(None),
              a.__getitem__(slice(None)).__iadd__(da.__getitem__(slice(None))))
```

This makes unnecessary copies of both lists.

Assuming `a` and `da` are lists, you could much more reasonably use the `extend()` method:

```
a.extend(da)
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to modify a list in place, rather than replace it with a new list, you need to use the slicing syntax.

```
a[:] = da[:]
```

In this case though, `+=` will *always* modify the list in place, so the slicing is redundant.

This might be a perfect example of [cargo cult programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming).