# group argmax/argmin over partitioning indices in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Numpy's `ufunc`s have a [`reduceat`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduceat.html) method which runs them over contiguous partitions within an array. So instead of writing:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([4, 0, 6, 8, 0, 9, 8, 5, 4, 9])
split_at = [4, 5]
maxima = [max(subarray for subarray in np.split(a, split_at)]
```

I can write:

```
maxima = np.maximum.reduceat(a, np.hstack([0, split_at]))
```

Both will return the maximum values in slices `a[0:4]`, `a[4:5]`, `a[5:10]`, being `[8, 0, 9]`.

I would like a similar function to perform [`argmax`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html), noting that I would only like a *single* maximum index in each partition: `[3, 4, 5]` with the above `a` and `split_at` (despite indices 5 and 9 both obtaining the maximum value in the last group), as would be returned by

```
np.hstack([0, split_at]) + [np.argmax(subarray) for subarray in np.split(a, split_at)]
```

I will post a possible solution below, but would like to see one that is vectorized without creating an index over groups.

Answer (score 1):

This solution involves building an index over groups (`[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]` in the above example).

```
group_lengths = np.diff(np.hstack([0, split_at, len(a)]))
n_groups = len(group_lengths)
index = np.repeat(np.arange(n_groups), group_lengths)
```

Then we can use:

```
maxima = np.maximum.reduceat(a, np.hstack([0, split_at]))
all_argmax = np.flatnonzero(np.repeat(maxima, group_lengths) == a)
result = np.empty(len(group_lengths), dtype='i')
result[index[all_argmax[::-1]]] = all_argmax[::-1]
```

To get `[3, 4, 5]` in `result`. The `[::-1]`s ensure that we get the *first* rather than the last argmax in each group.

This relies on the fact that the last index in fancy assignment determines the value assigned, which @seberg [says one shouldn't rely on](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16026109/1017546) (and a safer alternative can be achieved with `result = all_argmax[np.unique(index[all_argmax], return_index=True)[1]]`, which involves a sort over `len(maxima) ~ n_groups` elements).

Comment: This has algorithmic complexity similar to your `np.unique` solution, but doesn't involve the `index` array at all. Once you have `all_argmax` you can directly do:  `all_argmax[np.searchsorted(all_argmax, np.hstack([0, split_at]))]`.

Comment: Thanks, @Jaime, `searchsorted` always turns up in places I don't think of it.

Comment: @Jaime your proposed solution doesn't give me the same result as the `np.unique` implementation. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, the code I wrote is obviously wrong: `all_argmax` is a non-sorted array, so you can't call `np.searchsorted` on it. I haven't run it, so bugs may remain, but I think there's a `np.nonzero()` call missing around the innermost `all_argmax`, i.e.: `all_argmax[np.searchsorted(np.nonzero(all_argmax), np.hstack([0, split_at]))]`

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by this question, ive added argmin/max functionality to the [numpy_indexed](https://github.com/EelcoHoogendoorn/Numpy_arraysetops_EP) package. Here is what the corresponding test looks like. Note that the keys may be in any order (and of any kind supported by npi):

```
def test_argmin():
    keys   = [2, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
    values = [4, 5, 6, 8, 0, 9, 8, 5, 4, 9]
    unique, amin = group_by(keys).argmin(values)
    npt.assert_equal(unique, [0, 1, 2])
    npt.assert_equal(amin,   [1, 4, 0])
```