# efficient setting 1D range values in a DataFrame (or a ndarray) with boolean array

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

PREREQUISITE

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
```

INPUT1:boolean 2d array (a sample array as below)

```
x = np.array(
    [[False,False,False,False,True],
     [True,False,False,False,False],
     [False,False,True,False,True],
     [False,True,True,False,False],
     [False,False,False,False,False]])
```

INPUT2:1D Range values (a sample as below)

```
y=np.array([1,2,3,4])
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:2D ndarray

```
   [[0,0,0,0,1],
    [1,0,0,0,2],
    [2,0,1,0,1],
    [3,1,1,0,2],
    [4,2,2,0,3]]
```

I want to set a range value(vertical vector) for each True in 2d ndarray(INPUT1) efficiently. Is there some useful APIs or solutions for this purpose?

Comment: It would be much easier if your example input didn't have all ones. Also I don't understand how you end up with that result.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I edited my question for clarity.

Comment: Could there be more than one True value in any one of the columns (vertical vector)?

Comment: Divakar. Yes, It is possible. I edited my question to define the behavior if there is more than one True value in the range of vertical vector. (scan True values from the top to the bottom of INPUT1)

Comment: Could you add a case with two True in a column and being separated by at least one False?

Comment: Divakar. I added a new column to INPUT1 and EXPECTED OUTPUT.

Comment: Next time I suggest pinging @Divakar like this, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I couldn't come up with an elegant solution, so I came up with multiple inelegant ones. The two main approaches I could think of are

1. brute-force looping over each `True` value and assigning slices, and
2. using a single indexed assignment to replace the necessary values.

It turns out that the time complexity of these approaches is non-trivial, so depending on the size of your array either can be faster.

Using your example input:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array(
    [[False,False,False,False,True],
     [True,False,False,False,False],
     [False,False,True,False,True],
     [False,True,True,False,False],
     [False,False,False,False,False]])
y = np.array([1,2,3,4])
refout = np.array([[0,0,0,0,1],
    [1,0,0,0,2],
    [2,0,1,0,1],
    [3,1,1,0,2],
    [4,2,2,0,3]])

# alternative input with arbitrary size:
# N = 100; x = np.random.rand(N,N) < 0.2; y = np.arange(1,N)

def looping_clip(x, y):
    """Loop over Trues, use clipped slices"""
    nmax = x.shape[0]
    n = y.size

    # initialize output
    out = np.zeros_like(x, dtype=y.dtype)
    # loop over True values
    for i,j in zip(*x.nonzero()):
        # truncate right-hand side where necessary
        out[i:i+n, j] = y[:nmax-i]
    return out

def looping_expand(x, y):
    """Loop over Trues, use an expanded buffer"""
    n = y.size
    nmax,mmax = x.shape
    ivals,jvals = x.nonzero()

    # initialize buffed-up output
    out = np.zeros((nmax + max(n + ivals.max() - nmax,0), mmax), dtype=y.dtype)
    # loop over True values
    for i,j in zip(ivals, jvals):
        # slice will always be complete, i.e. of length y.size
        out[i:i+n, j] = y
    return out[:nmax, :].copy() # rather not return a view to an auxiliary array

def index_2d(x, y):
    """Assign directly with 2d indices, use an expanded buffer"""
    n = y.size
    nmax,mmax = x.shape
    ivals,jvals = x.nonzero()

    # initialize buffed-up output
    out = np.zeros((nmax + max(n + ivals.max() - nmax,0), mmax), dtype=y.dtype)

    # now we can safely index for each "(ivals:ivals+n, jvals)" so to speak
    upped_ivals = ivals[:,None] + np.arange(n) # shape (ntrues, n)
    upped_jvals = jvals.repeat(y.size).reshape(-1, n) # shape (ntrues, n)

    out[upped_ivals, upped_jvals] = y # right-hand size of shape (n,) broadcasts

    return out[:nmax, :].copy() # rather not return a view to an auxiliary array

def index_1d(x,y):
    """Assign using linear indices, use an expanded buffer"""
    n = y.size
    nmax,mmax = x.shape
    ivals,jvals = x.nonzero()

    # initialize buffed-up output
    out = np.zeros((nmax + max(n + ivals.max() - nmax,0), mmax), dtype=y.dtype)

    # grab linear indices corresponding to Trues in a buffed-up array
    inds = np.ravel_multi_index((ivals, jvals), out.shape)

    # now all we need to do is start stepping along rows for each item and assign y
    upped_inds = inds[:,None] + mmax*np.arange(n) # shape (ntrues, n)

    out.flat[upped_inds] = y  # y of shape (n,) broadcasts to (ntrues, n)

    return out[:nmax, :].copy() # rather not return a view to an auxiliary array


# check that the results are correct
print(all([np.array_equal(refout, looping_clip(x,y)),
           np.array_equal(refout, looping_expand(x,y)),
           np.array_equal(refout, index_2d(x,y)),
           np.array_equal(refout, index_1d(x,y))]))
```

I tried to document each function, but here's a synopsis:

1. `looping_clip` loops over every `True` value in the input and assigns to a corresponding slice in the output. We take care on the right-hand side to shorten the assigned array for when part of the slice would go beyond the edge of the array along the first dimension.
2. `looping_expand` loops over every `True` value in the input and assigns to a corresponding *full* slice in the output after allocating a padded output array ensuring that every slice will be full. We do more work when allocating a larger output array, but we don't have to shorten the right-hand side on assignment. We could omit the `.copy()` call in the last step, but I prefer not to return a nontrivially strided array (i.e. a view to an auxiliary array rather than a proper copy) as this might lead to obscure surprises for the user.
3. `index_2d` computes the 2d indices of every value to be assigned to, and assumes that duplicate indices will be handled in order. This is not guaranteed! (More on this a bit later.)
4. `index_1d` does the same using linearized indices and indexing into the `flatiter` of the output.

Here are the timings of the above methods using random arrays (see the commented line near the start):

[image: timings: indexing versions are only faster for medium-sized inputs of N around 10-150]

What we can see is that for small and large arrays the looping versions are faster, but for linear sizes between roughly 10 and 150 the indexing versions are better. The reason I didn't go to higher sizes is that the indexing cases start to use a lot of memory, and I didn't want to have to worry about this messing with timings.

Just to make the above worse, note that the indexing versions assume that duplicate indices in a fancy indexing scenario are handled in order, so when `True` values are handled which are "lower" in the array, previous values will be overwritten as per your requirements. There's only one problem: [this is not guaranteed](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#detailed-notes):

> For advanced assignments, there is in general no guarantee for the iteration order. This means that if an element is set more than once, it is not possible to predict the final result.

This doesn't sounds very encouraging. While in my experiments it seems that the indices are handled in order (according to C order), this can also be coincidence, or an implementation detail. So if you want to use the indexing versions, make sure that on your specific version and specific dimensions and shapes this still holds true.

We *can* make the assignment safer by getting rid of duplicate indices ourselves. For this we can make use of [this answer by Divakar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44672126/5067311) on a corresponding question:

```
def index_1d_safe(x,y):
    """Same as index_1d but use Divakar's safe solution for reducing duplicates"""
    n = y.size
    nmax,mmax = x.shape
    ivals,jvals = x.nonzero()

    # initialize buffed-up output
    out = np.zeros((nmax + max(n + ivals.max() - nmax,0), mmax), dtype=y.dtype)

    # grab linear indices corresponding to Trues in a buffed-up array
    inds = np.ravel_multi_index((ivals, jvals), out.shape)

    # now all we need to do is start stepping along rows for each item and assign y
    upped_inds = inds[:,None] + mmax*np.arange(n) # shape (ntrues, n)

    # now comes https://stackoverflow.com/a/44672126
    # need additional step: flatten upped_inds and corresponding y values for selection
    upped_flat_inds = upped_inds.ravel() # shape (ntrues, n) -> (ntrues*n,)
    y_vals = np.broadcast_to(y, upped_inds.shape).ravel() # shape (ntrues, n) -> (ntrues*n,)

    sidx = upped_flat_inds.argsort(kind='mergesort')
    sindex = upped_flat_inds[sidx]
    idx = sidx[np.r_[np.flatnonzero(sindex[1:] != sindex[:-1]), upped_flat_inds.size-1]]
    out.flat[upped_flat_inds[idx]] = y_vals[idx]

    return out[:nmax, :].copy() # rather not return a view to an auxiliary array
```

This still reproduces your expected output. The problem is that now the function takes much longer to finish:

[image: updated timing figure: safe 1d indexing case is always slower]

Bummer. Considering how my indexing versions are only faster for an intermediate array size and how their faster versions are not guaranteed to work, perhaps it's simplest to just use one of the looping versions. This is not to say, of course, that there aren't any optimal vectorized solutions that I missed.

Comment: thanks a lot for your thoughtful code and detailed explanation. I try to use the looping version and if I find other solutions, I write it in this place.

Comment: @naokifujita glad I could help. And yes, please, if you find other alternatives, don't hesitate to post here yourself, and feel free to ping me with it :)