# How to add elements to a 2D array using python fancy indexing?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I am writing a program in python and I want to vectorize it as much as possible. I have the following variables

1. 2D array of zeros `E` with shape `(L,T)`.
2. array `w` with shape `(N,)` with arbitrary values.
3. array `index` with shape `(A,)` whose values are integers between `0` and `N-1`. The values are unique.
4. array `labels` with a shape the same as `w` (`(A,)`), whose values are integers between `0` and `L-1`. **The values are not necessarily unique.**
5. Integer `t` between `0` and `T-1`.

We want to add the values of `w` at indices `index` to the array `E` at rows `labels` and column `t`. I used the following code:

```
E[labels,t] += w[index]
```

But this approach does not give desired results. For example,

```
import numpy as np

E = np.zeros([10,1])
w = np.arange(0,100)
index = np.array([1,3,4,12,80])
labels = np.array([0,0,5,5,2])
t = 0
E[labels,t] += w[index]
```

Gives

```
array([[ 3.],
   [ 0.],
   [80.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [12.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.]])
```

But the correct answer would be

```
array([[ 4.],
       [ 0.],
       [80.],
       [ 0.],
       [ 0.],
       [16.],
       [ 0.],
       [ 0.],
       [ 0.],
       [ 0.]])
```

Is there a way to achieve this behavior without using a for loop?

I realized I can use this: `np.add.at(E,[labels,t],w[index])` but it gives me this warning:

```
FutureWarning: Using a non-tuple sequence for multidimensional indexing is deprecated; use `arr[tuple(seq)]` instead of `arr[seq]`. In the future this will be interpreted as an array index, `arr[np.array(seq)]`, which will result either in an error or a different result.
```

Comment: I'm sorry but what is `indices`?? I think you mean `index`..right??

Comment: As the warning indicates use a tuple like `np.add.at(E, (labels, t), w[index])` instead of passing a `list`.

Answer (score 1):

Pulled from a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15973827/handling-of-duplicate-indices-in-numpy-assignments), you can use [np.bincount()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html) to achieve your goal:

```
import numpy as np
import time

E = np.zeros([10,1])
w = np.arange(0,100)
index = np.array([1,3,4,12,80])
labels = np.array([0,0,5,5,2])
t = 0

# --------- Using np.bincount()
start = time.perf_counter()
for _ in range(10000):
    E = np.zeros([10,1])
    values = w[index]
    result = np.bincount(labels, values, E.shape[0])
    E[:, t] += result
print("Bin count time: {}".format(time.perf_counter() - start))
print(E)


# --------- Using for loop
for _ in range(10000):
    E = np.zeros([10,1])
    for i, in_ in enumerate(index):
        E[labels[i], t] += w[in_]
print("For loop time: {}".format(time.perf_counter() - start))
print(E)
```

Gives:

```
Bin count time: 0.045003452
[[ 4.]
 [ 0.]
 [80.]
 [ 0.]
 [ 0.]
 [16.]
 [ 0.]
 [ 0.]
 [ 0.]
 [ 0.]]
For loop time: 0.09853353699999998
[[ 4.]
 [ 0.]
 [80.]
 [ 0.]
 [ 0.]
 [16.]
 [ 0.]
 [ 0.]
 [ 0.]
 [ 0.]]
```

Comment: `np.bincount` has a limitation, its input must be non-negative ints.

Comment: Agreed, but easily solvable by a quick one-liner to convert negative indices to positive. The weights don’t have to be non-negative ints.