# Cannot perform arithmetic operations more than once per element on a numpy array via slicing

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list of coordinates, and a map. For each of these coordinates, I would like to add 10 to the map. If I try to use the plus equal operator, however, it only seems to add once, and then never again. The same behavior happens if I pull it out and add 10 to it, both ways shown below:

```
coordinates = np.asarray(np.random.randint(0,10,(1000,2)))
map_array = np.zeros((10,10))

map_array[coordinates[:,0], coordinates[:,1]] += 10 #If a coordinate is repeated, it doesn't add 10 to it again 
#map_array[coordinates[:,0], coordinates[:,1]] = map_array[coordinates[:,0], coordinates[:,1]] + 10 #same as above
```

Output of map_array:

```
[[10., 10., 10., 10., 10., 10., 10., 10., 10., 10.],
[10., 10., 10., 10., 10., 10., 10., 10., 10., 10.],
[10., 10., 10., 10., 10., 10., 10., 10., 10., 10.],
[10., 10., 10., 10., 10., 10., 10., 10., 10., 10.],
[10., 10., 10., 10., 10., 10., 10., 10., 10., 10.],
[10., 10., 10., 10., 10., 10., 10., 10., 10., 10.],
[10., 10., 10., 10., 10., 10., 10., 10., 10., 10.],
[10., 10., 10., 10., 10., 10., 10., 10., 10., 10.],
[10., 10., 10., 10., 10., 10., 10., 10., 10., 10.],
[10., 10., 10., 10., 10., 10., 10., 10., 10., 10.]
```

However, when I iterate through each of the coordinates and add 10 to each one that way, it seems to work fine.

```
for i in coordinates[:]:
    map_array[i[0], i[1]] +=10
```

Output of map_array:

```
[[110.,  90., 160.,  90.,  70.,  70., 140., 110.,  70.,  90.],
[ 90., 130.,  90.,  70., 130., 110., 130., 100., 120.,  90.],
[140., 100., 110., 110., 120.,  60., 140., 110.,  90.,  70.],
[120.,  90., 130., 110., 120.,  90., 100., 170., 100., 100.],
[160., 120., 130., 110., 130.,  80., 140.,  80., 180.,  70.],
[160., 160., 120., 100., 110.,  90.,  90.,  80., 120., 110.],
[120., 100., 120.,  80.,  90., 130., 130.,  60.,  90.,  90.],
[120.,  80., 160., 110., 100., 150., 130., 150., 120., 160.],
[160.,  80.,  90.,  30.,  90.,  80.,  40.,  80., 120., 160.],
[130., 120.,  80.,  90.,  80., 160., 130., 180., 100., 130.]]
```

I think the problem lies with numpy not wanting to select the same index more than once, because if I do this:

```
coordinates = np.asarray(np.random.randint(0,10,(10,2)))
map_array = np.zeros((10,10))

map_array[coordinates[:,0], coordinates[:,1]] += 10 #only adds once
```

Output of coordinates :

```
[[6, 1],
[1, 7],
[5, 5],
[5, 0],
[5, 4],
[7, 3],
[5, 6],
[6, 3],
[3, 2],
[0, 7]]
```

Output of map:

```
[[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0., 10.,  0.,  0.],
[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0., 10.,  0.,  0.],
[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
[ 0.,  0., 10.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
[10.,  0.,  0.,  0., 10., 10., 10.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
[ 0., 10.,  0., 10.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
[ 0.,  0.,  0., 10.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]]
```

We see that it's not blanket setting all of the elements to 10. Is there a way to not iterate through each element? I would like to use a Numpy builtin for speed.

Comment: This has been solved here:   https://stackoverflow.com/a/73958805.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that it's already been solved here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/73958805

The function in my case is

```
np.add.at(map_array,(coordinates[:,0],coordinates[:,1]),10)
```